# overlay picture frames in real-time to your camera's view

Tags: iphone, ios6

On Itunes store there is an app called **[Photoframes Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/my/app/photoframes-pro/id374202806?mt=8)** by iCoder, where I can import my own frame/s into the app and see that frame in my camera view. Shooting the photo will result a copy of that photo with the frame in the camera roll. This app has not been updated since 2010 and the programmer is a  major developer ripper.

I was wondering if anyone knows of an existing app that can do the same or assisting in creating something similar.

Please note that I am not a programmer/developer so layman's terms would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.
Jerome

Answer (score 0):

you can add overlayView on `UIImagePickerController` with its `cameraOverlayView` property..

```
yourImagePicker.cameraOverlayView = yourOverLayView;//set view as a overlay with your image here
```

See this tutorial with explaination :  [iOS Camera Overlay Example Using AVCaptureSession](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273)

i hope this help you...

Comment: @JeromeLee see this tutorial with demo dude.. :)